# How to call a method of a COM interface if you have the IntPtr?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, filedialog

In Windows, I want to grab a FileOpenDialog that already exists in another process, as a child of another application and force it to navigate to a specific folder. I have hope that COM interop can help accomplish this. As I'm doing some research, I'm trying to first just open a new dialog using COM, but I'm stuck at a point. I can get an IntPtr to a dialog instance and an IntPtr to its interface that has the method I want to call, but I don't know the proper technique to call it. Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    // the implementation COM object: FileOpenDialog
    var classId = new Guid("DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7");
    var fileOpenDialogType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(classId, true);
    var fileOpenDialog = Activator.CreateInstance(fileOpenDialogType);            
    IntPtr pUnknown = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(fileOpenDialog);

    // the COM interface: IFileOpenDialog
    var interfaceId = new Guid("d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960");
    var result = Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnknown, ref interfaceId, out IntPtr pIFileOpenDialog);

    // at this point:
    // result = 0
    // pIFileOpenDialog = some non-zero value (for a memory address, I assume)

    // But how can I invoke the "Show" method of the dialog? Something like this:
    //Invoke("Show", pIFileOpenDialog);

    Marshal.Release(pUnknown);
    Marshal.Release(pIFileOpenDialog);
}
```

Comment: IFileOpenDialog is provided by an in-process server.  Which means that this code will never work, you always get your own copy.  You could only manipulate it with code injection or UI Automation.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm open to anything to get it done. Could you point me to some resources on code injection and UI Automation?